# Creating complicated models using scripts

Tags: modeling, scripting

I'm new to blender and 3d modeling in general, but I have a python background. While searching I found models created via scripting. These models were good, but the general idea was creating repetitive elements like cubes or toruses to form a different object. So I was curious about the limits. Is there a thing that scripts can't do, but we can do via GUI, or is there no limitations at all?

Edit: I was asking the limitations of the scripts, and couldn't understand how this question was opinion based.

So again let me ask in this way. Is there any way that I can create a human model with scripts? That's the only thing I want to know.

Comment: There are plenty of things you can't do with scripts because they require a UI or live interaction, and there are plenty of things not practical to do by hand because they are tedious. Why people do or do not is subjective and only they can answer. There are plenty of addons around to create "complex models" from human figures to vegetation

Comment: Welcome.   Attempt to make your questions less subjective, and not those that can be answered simply yes / no _eg_. _"Can I create a human model with scripts"_   To which I would answer yes.  Recommend checking out the bmesh module. The [create chain links example](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#operator-example)  Have a go at making a humanoid form from a cuboid with bmesh.  If and when you get stuck post a question here, cos in the end the sky's the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts (as far as I know) can access almost every part of Blender. There are scripts to create relatively complex objects, but they are usually add-ons instead. For example, there are add-ons to create trees and mountains.

To answer the rest of your question, scripts to generate complex meshes are not usually seen for two primary reasons:

1. Usually complex meshes require much care and an artist's touch. The artist wants complete control over the creation, and will use scripts only to create the simple pieces that are repetitive, then put them together into a more complex mesh. This is good, because computers aren't creative, but are very good at creating lots of things with simple variations.
2. Scripts to generate complex objects that are not extremely simple are usually broken out into separate programs. For an artist to relinquish control of their hand in the art to a program to generate, or in many cases, simulate, they still need to have lots of options to control the simulation. They want the program to be complicated and advanced, with lots of options. This is why, usually, scripts to generate mountains, trees, or people are often separate programs, then the meshes are just imported. Some examples are [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/), [The Grove](https://www.thegrove3d.com/), and [World Machine](https://www.world-machine.com/). These programs have all had much work put into them as standalone programs that are useful in their own right. The other benefit of this is that now these generated meshes can be used in (mostly) any 3D software.

Comment: What if the model is something like a furniture, or things that require precision rather than creativity. For example a table, knife, or any machinelike object. I had a project in my mind about this, and I'm looking forward to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Usually in cases such as this, artists prefer to use asset libraries. That way, they can be sure that the model is created in an aesthetic manner by another artist. It also helps because usually the artist can look through a wide variety of options and see how they will look beforehand. For most artists, programming is a bit mystical, so they much prefer to look at a finished picture rather than code and parameters.

Comment: The main time I can think of when something like a script is used for that sort of thing is when the artist values the accuracy of their model. For example, as you stated, a knife. If they want to have a specific curve on the edge of a knife to visualize how it would be made or how it would look, they may use math in a script to ensure it is exact. This is often used in more science backgrounds, if one exact shape or size is meant to be the most effective. However, this is still quite impractical unless there is a known mathmatical formula for how the object should be made.

Comment: Another time I can think of where this might be used is in 3D printing. Sometimes 3D models require certain sizes or thicknesses of parts, and a script can help ensure this is done correctly. Still, usually the main model is created by hand and the script only modifies it. It is also worth keeping in mind that almost anything used in Blender could be considered a script to create geometry. Adding a circle is a script to add a perfect circle. The solidify modifier is a script to give a 2D object volume. Even adding a plane is a script to create four points with a face.

Comment: So in this way, almost everything in Blender is some sort of script to generate or modify geometry. The artist just controls them, chooses which ones to use, and the modifies the output.

Comment: Poster: "Computer's aren't creative".
The AI boom:

Comment: Ah, too true, too true, lol. LLMs truely are amazing.